# trazer dados do banco conforme outro dado cadastrado

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, jquery-datatables, where

Tenho um código que traz os dados do banco e gera uma tabela. Esses dados está vindo todos que estão cadastrados, mas preciso que apenas os dados com o mesmo Estado do usuário venha.

**Por Exemplo:** Tenho um usuário de Santa Catarina, preciso com que venha os dados do banco apenas os de Santa Catarina.

Meu código é em ***CodeIgniter***, e no Model que traz essas informações esta assim:

```
 $this->datatables->select('lau.l_id, lau.l_tipo, emp.e_nome, lau.l_d_h, usr.usr_nome, lau.l_status');
                $this->datatables->from('lau');
                $this->datatables->join('usr', 'lau.u._id = usr.u._id');
                $this->datatables->join('disp', 'lau.d_id = disp.d_id');
                $this->datatables->join('emp', 'emp.e_id = usr.e_id');
                return $this->datatables->generate();
    }
```

Comment: E qual é o resultado deste código?

Comment: Você terá que usar o WHERE ($this->where('estado', 'SC');  para filtrar os resultados

Comment: @AndréBaill seu código funcionou em partes: a parte que funcionou foi a parte mais importante que é pegar apenas os relatórios de SC. Porém, preciso fazer com que ele pegue os relatórios conforme o estado que o usuário cadastrou. Se ele for de São Paulo, precisa pegar todos os relatórios de São Paulo

Comment: Entendi, mas você pode fazer um group by por estado, e trazer novos resultados através de um foreach()

Comment: @AndréBaill como é com datatables, eu tentei fazer o group by anteriormente, mas ele não funciona. Não sei ao certo o motivo, já que eu peguei esse código apenas para modificar.

Comment: Nunca usei o datatables... mas ele gera uma tabela, isso? O que de resultado ele tras?

Comment: @AndréBaill ele gera uma tabela que ao clicar em suas colunas você ordena os dados de forma diferente. Os resultados você que escolhe, no caso dessa tabela ele traz resultados de todos os relatórios que tenho cadastrado no banco, mas preciso apenas do relatórios que tem o mesmo estado cadastrado na perfil do meu usuário.

Comment: Já pesquisei sobre isso.. Entendi perfeitamente, então você terá que trazer os resultados pelo LEFT JOIN, da forma que está ali em cima.. passando o WHERE também.. o que te gerou de resultados? O que está incorreto?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31402/discussion-between-ketlin-and-andre-baill).